Is there any analysis of who goes Interrailling?
It is on the news that TV presenter Kirsty Allsopp is being investigated by her local council over child protection concerns over her 15 years old sons Interrail trip in Europe after his GCSE's.
This surprises me as some decades ago when I finished my GCSE's many of my class mates went Interrailling.  From a quick google I failed to find any information about who actually goes Interrailling.  Is this information available?  Is it unusual for people this age to go Interrailling these days?

Most hostels do not allow solo travelers unless they're 16+ (and this was the case decades ago too) so traveling alone at 15 would be quite challenging.

@lambshaanxy The article details this, he is not traveling alone but with a 16-year old friend and actually turned 16 during the trip. It's not completely clear whether the fact he was 15 and not 16 at the start of the trip was relevant to the way the referral was treated but I guess the question is more about teenagers in the middle of secondary school vs. older students and not so much about the technicality of turning 16 in the later part of the summer.

@Relaxed Hostels usually require an adult guardian for under-16s, another friend of the same age isn't going to cut it.

@lambshaanxy I have no idea, why do you think that's usually required? Apparently, having one 16-year old was enough, in 9 separate places, Kirstie Allsopp specifically and explicitly mentioned that even before there was any controversy (and I was wrong, he turned 16 after coming back). I still don't think that's this is what the controversy or question are about.

@Relaxed It's the rule at most European YHA hostels, see eg https://www.yha.org.uk/our-policies/booking-terms/18

@lambshaanxy You are linking to conditions, which only apply in the UK. There are plenty of European countries, where persons under 16 are allowed to travel alone without a guardian, just to name a few, where I was easily able to check: Norway, Sweden, Denmark, Germany and most parts of Switzerland. There may of course still be hostels or accomodations where they don't want so young guests to be staying alone, but there are no legal regulations preventing it.

@Tor-EinarJarnbjo I'm not claiming travel is legally restricted. I'm saying a solo traveller under 16 will have trouble finding accommodation in many countries.  It's not just the UK, eg France has the same rule: https://www.auberges-de-jeunesse.com/en/questions/

@lambshaanxy That rule is very different "Is there an age limit for staying at a Youth Hostel ?  Youth Hostels are open to everyone. Some establishments will not admit children below a certain age. It is preferable to check with the Hostel." vs. "children under the age of 16 must be accompanied by a person who is 18 years or older"

@User65535 Keep reading. "Q: Are minors admitted on their own at the Youth Hostels? A: Unaccompanied minors aged 16 to 18 are accepted on presentation of a parental authorisation duly completed and accompanied by a copy of the national identity card of the legal guardian."  By implication, under 16 is not accepted at all.

@lambshaanxy And I am saying that there are many European countries, where solo travellers under 16 will not have a problem finding accomodation. In your comment, you are talking about 'European YHA hostels', which does not make sence, since YHA is the UK Youth Hostels Association. The conditions you are linking to are irrelevant for youth hostels in all other European countries.

@lambshaanxy ... and has been so for over 90 years. An exception of the rule should never be considered the general rule.


Is it unusual for people this age to go Interrailling these days?

Interrail was created in 1972 and an age limit existed up to 21. Since 1994 it is up to 27 (Youth Pass) and over the age of 60 (Senior discount). (Interrail Youth Pass Discounts | Interrail Pass Up to 25% discount | Interrail.eu)
For youth Hostels, in Germany since 1919 and in Europe since 1932 were intended for young peaple (minors). In Germany membership is possible with 14.
This is still true today Hostel FAQs  – Hostelling International - Who can stay at a hostel? Is there an age limit?:

There is no age limit and our hostels welcome solo travellers, friends, families, groups and more…
...
However, minors under the age of 18 will need to provide a permission from a legal guardian to stay unaccompanied in a hostel.

Other that that a permission form seems to be now required, nothing much has changed since the 1970's (both for Interrail and Youth Hostels).

is being investigated by her local council over child protection concerns over her 15 years old sons Interrail trip in Europe after his GCSE's.

It took me less than 5 minutes to find the information that resolves the local councils concerns.
If they need longer, then questions should be asked as to the reason why.

Anyone can get a IR pass, not only < 27 and > 60

@NicolasFormichella The point of this answer is that this pass was originally (and still is) mainly intended for young peaple, including Great Britain: Trains in Great Britain | Interrail.eu

Your wording makes it seems like there is an age limit to get one

@NicolasFormichella Not when the question is about a parent being investigated because they allowed their 15 year old to use the Interrail offer. This is an answer to that question and not about the general usage of Interrail.
